# Expect: Modify Ctrl-C Behavior 

Tags: exec, expect, sigint

While exec is running a program, I would like Ctrl-C to terminate the program and resume the script, instead of killing the script. What's the best way of accomplishing that?

Comment: To stop a program send SIGSTOP, usually mapped to Ctl-Z. If run under expect you should be able to use kill command with SIGSTOP, but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the program using `exec` and using expect's `trap` command to intercept SIGINT. The subprogram is still terminated (in fact, there may not be a way to avoid this is using `exec`), but by using `trap` and a `catch` around `exec`, the tcl script can continue executing.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works: `package require Tclx`

If it can, then you can trap signals with the [`signal`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1886) command.

Comment: expect is supposed to have [its own facility](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Handle_a_signal#Tcl) for catching signals. The problem is that, assuming that the initial SIGINT is sent to `expect` and my script catches it, I'd need to send a SIGINT to the program being `exec`uted, but I don't know how to get its PID. `exec` only returns a PID if you background the process, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @LaC, why don't you `spawn` it instead of `exec`'ing it?

Comment: I used `exec` because I just want to run the program until it completes. I tried using `spawn` followed by `wait`, but that makes it completely impervious to SIGINT. I ended up having to suspend and kill -9. I tried installing a signal handler for SIGINT but it does not get called.